# Position dynamic box in center + bottom

Tags: css, html, cross-browser, center

http://pastehtml.com/view/bfzerlo1m.html

How do I position the red box in the CENTER + in the BOTTOM of the orange div?

Both height and width of the red box is dynamic and different from box to box..

(It needs to work in all browsers including IE7 + IE8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML

```
<DIV class="wrapper"><div class="redbox"></div></div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
.redbox{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Won't he need to set 100% width on the wrapper?

Comment: The wrapper is not the orange area. Is a helper to put it in the bottom. But he will have to put position:relative; to the element with the orange background.

Comment: Not what I meant, the orange box already has position: relative in his example - your wrapper div will need 100% width in order to span the full width of the orange box so that the red box inside it can be centered in it. Otherwise, the wrapper will only be as large as the red box and it will sit on the left.

Comment: Im pretty sure the div will spread by default 100% width, but for the sake of it, I will improve it.

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements do not automatically fill the width of their parent, they shrink to fit their contents unless they're given an explicit width : )

Answer (score 1):

SpaceBeers solution seems fine - or another variant:

http://jsfiddle.net/yPAey/

Answer (score 0):

To account for variable width in the red box, add another wrapper div around the the red box width 'position: absolute' and 'bottom: 0' and 'width: 100%' - then remove the position:absolute from the red box letting it center itself with the 'margin: 0 auto'

```
.wrap {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.redbox {
    height: ?px;
    width: ?px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code with the red box centered:

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/nyndk/1/

I've aligned to the bottom a container (in blue) and then centered the red box in there.

Comment: This will work if you know what the width of the redbox will be, of course

Comment: Good point. I've amended the example to take that into account.

Comment: Yeah well, thats what I wrote :P

Comment: @Dbugger: it's what you wrote, except you didn't put 100% width on the wrapper div - which is what makes this work.

Comment: Does that mean we both win? :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do like this:

**HTML**

```
<div style="" class="parent">     
    <div class="child-wrap">         
        <div class="child">center me...</div>     
    </div>     
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent{
    width:180px;
    height:180px;
    position:relative;
    background:orange;
}
.child-wrap{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}
.child{
    background:red;
    top:-50%;
    margin-left:-50%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/FQsuU/